# Injecting Angular app with Chrome Extension Content Script: "App Already Bootstrapped with this Element ''"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Chrome extension content script, which injects an angular application into a page.  When the page loads, I get the following error:

> Error: ng:btstrpd App Already Bootstrapped with this Element

However, my content script only calls angular.bootstrap once. This is how it is being injected and bootstrapped:

```
var angularDiv = document.querySelector('#content');
angular.bootstrap(angularDiv, ['SESApp']);
angularDiv.classList.add('ng-app');
angularDiv.classList.add('ng-csp');
```

I have a stripped down version of my angular app and content script here:

https://gist.github.com/hedgerh/e73cd1136f1f1d453ee2

If anyone knows what's going on, I would greatly appreciate the help.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to add the `ng-app` class after the bootstraping? Try removing that `angularDiv.classList.add('ng-app');` statement and see if it's working or not.

Comment: Also move the `angularDiv.classList.add('ng-csp');` up to before `angular.bootstrap`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, there are situations where I need to inject two templates into a page and need to bootstrap the app in an element that is a parent of both of them.  I tried moving ng-csp above and even tried erasing both of the lines adding ng-app and ng-csp, I still get the bootstrap error.

Comment: May be you could try debugging or adding `console.log()` around the `angular.bootstrap()` to see if that piece of code is run twice.

Comment: Looks like it is only being called once. I was originally using a chrome-angular skeleton as a framework that used requirejs.  I was just looking over his code and saw this.  Does this give you any hints as to what may be wrong? https://github.com/salsita/chrome-extension-skeleton-ng/blob/develop/code/js/content.js

Comment: How does the injected HTML look like ? Does the page use Angular too ? What version of Angular are you using and what is the exact error message ?

Comment: each template is just a view with an ng-controller attribute at the top div. no ng-app or ng-csp. There are situations where I need to inject two templates onto one page, so I can't add ng-app to the templates. It worked when I was using requirejs, but doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: If you are sure that in html files there is no `ng-app`, my another guess is that is it possible that your extension is conflict with another extension like `Angular Batarang`?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I figured it out. The 'App already boostrapped' error disappeared somehow, but then I realized I was attempting to bootstrap the app outside of my template loader's success callback, so the app was bootstrapping before the view was loaded. Thanks for your help!